# Pegar todos valore do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém poderia me ajudar a descobrir o erro:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", 
"senha", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$sth = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $item){
 echo $item->id;
}
```

Eu queria pegar os valores do banco e imprimi-los, tentei usando o fetchAll, porém nem consegui êxito.

Comment: Só para esclarecer, não tem `fetchAll()` como método, e nesse caso é desnecessário a utilização do `prepare` (não é errado, mas, é desnecessário, sem utilidade), até existe o `fetch_all` mas, ai a sintaxe é diferente, o ideal é como eu respondi, o dado resposta é mais coerente ao que precisa.

Comment: Bestfastfire, segue o manual oficial do PHP com o método `fetch_all()` da `mysqli` para você ver a sintaxe correta: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código inicial tem problemas de digitação e também falta comandos para funcionar, um exemplo básico do seu código é:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "senha", "dbname");


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $sth = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes");  
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->get_result();   

    $items = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach ($items as $row) 
    {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

e tem que tomar cuidado porque, o `fetch_all` funcione a partir do `PHP >= 5.3`.

Mas, sinceridade o seu código não precisa de `prepare` (*porque, nesse caso é sem utilidade*, utilize quando precisar preparar paramentos para essa `SQL`, ou seja, a sua `SQL` não tem e não precisa), com o `query` e o seu retorno com o método `fetch_assoc`, é mais simples e fácil de manipular nessa `SQL` sem parâmetro, um exemplo funcional com outra forma:

```php
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "senha", "dbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM clientes"))
    {
        while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
    }
```